Evaluating $\displaystyle\iint\limits_{A}\left(x^3-y^2z^4,2y^3,z^3-3y^2z\right)\cdot\overrightarrow{n}~\mathrm{d}S$, where $A$ is the unit sphere
This is from UCHICAGO (GRE Math Subject Test Preparation), Week $5$, Problem $14$.

Let $A$ be the unit $2$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $\overrightarrow{F}=\left(x^3-y^2z^4,2y^3,z^3-3y^2z\right)$ be a vector field. Let $\overrightarrow{n}$ be the outward-pointing normal. Evaluate $\displaystyle\iint\limits_{A}\overrightarrow{F}\cdot\overrightarrow{n}~\mathrm{d}S$.
$\begin{matrix}\text{(A) }3\pi && \text{(B) }\pi && \text{(C) }\dfrac{12\pi}{5} && \text{(D) }-\dfrac{3\pi}{2} && \text{(E) }0\end{matrix}$

My Attempt: (Could be wrong, or a possible typo in one of the options):
$\nabla\cdot\overrightarrow{F}=3x^2+6y^2+3z^2-3y^2=3\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)$
But $V~:~x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ (as we have a unit sphere)
Therefore $\nabla\cdot\overrightarrow{F}=3(1)=3$
$$\iint\limits_{A}\overrightarrow{F}\cdot\overrightarrow{n}~\mathrm{d}S=\iiint\limits_{V}\nabla\cdot\overrightarrow{F}~\mathrm{d}V$$
But the volume of the sphere is $\dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3=\dfrac{4}{3}\pi (1)^3=\dfrac{4}{3}\pi$
Therefore, $\displaystyle\iiint\limits_{V}\nabla\cdot\overrightarrow{F}~\mathrm{d}V=3\cdot \dfrac{4}{3}\pi r^3=4\pi$
But confusing as they say $\text{(C) }\dfrac{12\pi}{5}$ is correct

Either I am wrong, option $\text{(A)}$ should have $4\pi$ instead of $3\pi$, or option $\text{(B)}$ should have $4\pi$ instead of $\pi$, or maybe some other possibilities and typos in $\overrightarrow{F}$.
Can you please check if my solution is correct?

Your help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

The divergence of $F$ is equal to $3$ on the sphere, but not in the ball.
The answer C is correct.

Could you please show me how to evaluate it?

Your expression for divergence $\text{div} F = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is correct and is equal to $3r^2$ in spherical coordinates. Convert the volume element $dV$ to spherical coordinates and evaluate the integral of the divergence.
